# Equation Plotting using ContourPlot

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I wanted to plot this equation

```
Equation = (s^2 + a1^2 (-1 + s^2)) s^2 (-a1 + s) (a1 + 
  s) Sqrt[((-1 + s^2) (-a1^2 + s^2))/(s^2 + a1^2 (-1 + s^2))]
 Cos[2 Sqrt[((-1 + s^2) (-a1^2 + s^2))/(s^2 + a1^2 (-1 + s^2))]
   z] (-Sqrt[
    a4 (a2^2 - s^2)] (a5 Sqrt[a2^2 a4 - a3 s^2] + 
     a3 Sqrt[a2^2 a4 - a5 s^2]) Cosh[(Sqrt[a2^2 - s^2] z)/a2] - 
  a4 Sqrt[a2^2 a4 - a3 s^2] Sqrt[a2^2 a4 - a5 s^2]
    Sinh[(Sqrt[a2^2 - s^2] z)/a2] + 
  a3 a5 (-a2^2 + s^2) Sinh[Sqrt[1 - s^2/a2^2] z]) + 
  a2^2 Sin[
  2 Sqrt[((-1 + s^2) (-a1^2 + s^2))/(s^2 + a1^2 (-1 + s^2))]
   z] (a2^2 a4  (-a1^2 + s^2) Sqrt[
   1 - s^2/a2^2] (a3 a5  s^4 (-1 + s^2) - 
     Sqrt[1 - (a3 s^2)/(a2^2 a4)] Sqrt[
      1 - (a5 s^2)/(
       a2^2 a4)] (s^4 + a1^2 s^2 (-2 + s^2) - 
        a1^4 (-1 + s^2))) Cosh[
    Sqrt[1 - s^2/a2^2]
      z] - ((s^2 + a1^2 (-1 + s^2)) a1^4 a5 (a2^2 - s^2) Sqrt[
      1 - (a3 s^2)/(
       a2^2 a4)] - (s^2 + a1^2 (-1 + s^2)) 2 a1^2 a5  s^2 (a2^2 - 
        s^2) Sqrt[1 - (a3 s^2)/(a2^2 a4)] + 
     a5  s^4 (a2^2 - s^2) Sqrt[1 - (a3 s^2)/(a2^2 a4)] - 
     a2^2 a3 a4^2  s^4 (-1 + s^2) (-a1^2 + s^2) Sqrt[
      1 - (a5 s^2)/(a2^2 a4)]) Sinh[Sqrt[1 - s^2/a2^2] z]);
```

Using ContourPlot command

```
Sub = {a1 -> 1.3`10, a2 -> 1.2`10, a3 -> 1.5`10, a4 -> 2`10, 
 a5 -> 1.8`10};

AA1 = ContourPlot[{(Equation /. Sub) == 0.}, {z, 0`10, 9.9`10}, {s, 
0`10, 1.4`10}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"\[Omega]/k \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(c\), \(0\)]\)", 
 ""}, {"k \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(0\)]\)", ""}}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]
```

Unfortunately as a result I have the plot that looks like a mess
[image]

Where I believe it should be more smooth one, may I ask for any advice or suggestions to how may I improve my code.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the PlotPoints and MaxRecursion options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your plot may be right. It's just that your function is highly oscillatory and the plot limits are a bit off.

Specifically, compare these two `Plot3D`s with different `s` ranges:

```
GraphicsRow[{
  Plot3D[equation /. sub, {z, 0, 9.9}, {s, 0, 1.4}],
  Plot3D[equation /. sub, {z, 0, 9.9}, {s, 0.8, 1}]
  }, ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

The first one corresponds to the plot limits in your `ContourPlot`. Observe that the equation is undefined for large ranges of `s`. Taking these out of the plot range makes it a lot more understandable.

Doing the `ContourPlot` with these ranges (and setting `PlotPoints -> 50`, as @Szabolcs suggested):

```
sub = {a1 -> 1.3`10, a2 -> 1.2`10, a3 -> 1.5`10, a4 -> 2`10, a5 -> 1.8`10};
AA1 = ContourPlot[{(equation /. sub) == 0.}, {z, 0`10, 9.9`10}, {s, 0.8`10, 1.0`10}, 
  FrameLabel -> {{"\[Omega]/k \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(c\), \(0\)]\)", 
     ""}, {"k \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(0\)]\)", ""}}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help

Comment: @Alexander No worries. Thanks for the accept.